# Seeking shapefiles for global border crossings?

Tags: shapefile, data, africa

I am trying to find a shapefile or set of shapefiles that contain global border crossings. Basically, what are the points of transit between one country and another.

Does anyone know if this data is available?

I am particularly interested in crossings in Sub Saharan Africa, like Zambia, Zimbabwe, Malawi, etc., and around Syria.

I have already checked the usual sources of shapefiles and no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the location of a dataset on global border crossing points.

http://geonode.wfp.org/layers/geonode:wld_poi_bcp_wfp

Comment: That is not actually what you asked for - that is a set of border crossings specifically for **humanitarian** issues (refugee movements, repatriation, food movement, etc). There are many missing border crossings in that dataset.

Comment: @Simbamangu Ah thanks for letting me know. I did not realize that the humanitarian dataset did not have data on regular border crossings. Do you know if there is a source for the other crossings that are missing?

Comment: I don't know of a more general dataset, particularly for our region (eastern / southern Africa). Border crossings change quite regularly too!